# Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR while Laravel migrate

Tags: php, mysql, apache, laravel

When I run `php artisan migrate` on my local server (running by `php artisan serve`) I get the following error:

```
[ErrorExeption]
Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR
```

I tried also `php artisan migrate --database db_name`, output is like this:

```
[InvalidArgumentExeption]
Database [db_name] not configured.
```

My app/config/local/database.php looks like following:

```
'connections' => array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost', // also tried 127.0.0.1
        'database'  => 'db_name',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => 'mypassword',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    )
)
```

I'm sure MySQL works, I checked it via command line and phpMyAdmin.

Also I included `HostnameLookups On` inside my `httpd.conf`, then restarted apache, but nothing helps.

I use Laravel 4.2, Debian.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

P.S. Sorry for my English:)

UPD:
Output of `php artisan env` is `Current application environment: local`

UPD2:

I created simple route:

```
Route::get('/test', function() {
    return $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
});
```

It returns `::1`, but when I execute `echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];` in php interactive mode (php -a) I get a Notice: `Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR`

Comment: The database parameter passed to the migrate command should have the value of the database connection, not the database name: `php artisan migrate --database mysql`.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work, output is: `Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR`

Comment: Take a look to your .env file (in the app root directory). Maybe you'll find it there.

Comment: Could you please post the migration files. Because as far as I can tell there's no explicit use of `REMOTE_ADDR` in any packages related to Laravel, so I'm left to assume it has something to do with your implementation.

Comment: when you get an artisan error, that error has possibly nothing to do with the command currently tried to run with artisan, but with some any other coding error you recently made. Search in your code for any recent reference to REMOTE_ADDR.

Comment: You get that error when running from CLI, because when you run an artisan command there is no context of a remote address. Although the migration should never touch that particular line of code, try commenting it out and running the migration again.

Comment: `@Amarnasan` thanks a lot, you save my time. Indeed  I had a reference to `REMOTE_ADRR` in my code, when I've removed it migration has been done! Please, write your comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @daggett You got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get an `artisan` error, that error has possibly nothing to do with the command currently tried to run with `artisan`, but with some any other coding error you recently made. Search in your code for any recent reference to `REMOTE_ADDR`.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't done so, make sure you're accessing SERVER_ADDR using the $_SERVER array to obtain the value of SERVER_ADDR, which is an element of this array.

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
```

If that doesn't work, it may mean that your server doesn't provide that information.

From [PHP.net](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here.

Comment: Thanks, please, see UPD2