# Laravel migration [ErrorException] Undefined index: index_type

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, migration

I'm trying to migrate my laravel project.

But When I enter migrate command I'm getting this error.I didn't understand why its giving me this error when I'm trying to migrate my project.

```
[ErrorException]             
  Undefined index: index_type  



Exception trace:
 () at /var/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/MySqlSchemaManager.php:75
 Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError() at /var/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/MySqlSchemaManager.php:75
 Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\MySqlSchemaManager->_getPortableTableIndexesList() at /var/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/AbstractSchemaManager.php:193
 Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\AbstractSchemaManager->listTableIndexes() at /var/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/AbstractSchemaManager.php:286
 Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\AbstractSchemaManager->listTableDetails() at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/Grammar.php:320
 Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\Grammar->getChangedDiff() at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/Grammar.php:302
 Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\Grammar->compileChange() at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php:107
 Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint->toSql() at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php:82
 Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint->build() at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php:229
 Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder->build() at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php:130
 Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder->table() at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:237
 Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic() at /var/www/database/migrations/2016_10_25_222438_update_relationships_for_employee.php:20
 Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::table() at /var/www/database/migrations/2016_10_25_222438_update_relationships_for_employee.php:20
 UpdateRelationshipsForEmployee->up() at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:373
 Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->Illuminate\Database\Migrations\{closure}() at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:380
 Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->runMigration() at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:162
 Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->runUp() at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:130
 Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->runMigrationList() at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:97
 Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->run() at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php:66
 Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand->fire() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:508
 Illuminate\Container\Container->call() at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:169
 Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:256
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:155
 Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:185
 Illuminate\Console\Command->call() at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/RefreshCommand.php:66
 Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\RefreshCommand->fire() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:508
 Illuminate\Container\Container->call() at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:169
 Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:256
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:155
 Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:820
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:187
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:118
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:121
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() at /var/www/artisan:36
```

my migration file is below.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class UpdateRelationshipsForEmployee extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        //
        Schema::table('employee',function ($table){
            $table->integer('retail_id')->unsigned()->index()->change();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('employee', function ($table){
            $table->integer('retail_id')->change();
        });
        //

    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code from `/var/www/database/migrations/2016_10_25_222438_update_relationships_for_employee.php`

Comment: @aynber I just added my code to the post.

Comment: Try adding the index on a separate line. `$table->index('retail_id');`

Comment: When you get an `artisan` error, that error has possibly nothing to do with the command currently tried to run with `artisan`, but with some any other coding error you recently made. Search in your code for any recent reference to `index_type `. [Ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607990/undefined-index-remote-addr-while-laravel-migrate)

Comment: I already searched but I don't have a referance to index_type

Comment: @Amit Sure. But here the error specifically refer to `2016_10_25_222438_update_relationships_for_employee.php:20`

Comment: @MuratKaya it could be caused by another migration that you have deleted.

Comment: actually I'm trying to deploy my project to the server so I just clone my project from git. After install composer I just run the php artisan migrate command and I'm getting this error.

Comment: also this migration tables are working on localhost without error @Wistar

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the total database and run the command 
 php artisan migrate:refresh --seed

Also you can maintain your database.
Just copy your model and migration information. 
Then Delete.
After deleting recreate model and table.

Now. go to your database migrations table. Delete the employee row.
Now. delete your employee table.

Now just terminal command  php artisan migrate

Comment: Ye, just drop the database and `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score -1):

Check your os locale or php locale,

cannot convert capital case correctly in dependent library used by laravel because your locale is different from en_us.UTF8

try

setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.UTF8');

Use en_us.UTF8 for case transformations regardless of the active locale.